How to make italic underline text in telegram using bot api, with link inside?
I'm writing my own bot using Telegram Bot API and C#.
I want to know, how to make at same time text italic and underline and also pass some hyperlink inside any word in this formatted text?

I want to make a message like on the screenshot presented above.

You should use MarkdownV2 as the sendMessage parse_mode, then you can

Create italic text using _some text_
Create a hyperlink using [some text](https://google.com)
Create underlined text using __some text__


Combining those:
_Some italic text with a __[hyperlink](https://google.com)___

Will send a message like:

